# Is it possible to dynamically inject text file contents to JSON array objects using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

### Summary

Starting from a JSON array, I'd like to replace an attribute of each item by the contents of a text file.

**Example:**

We have this initial JSON array:

```js
[ 
    { "name": "step-a", "message": "step-a message placeholder" },
    { "name": "step-b", "message": "step-b message placeholder" }
]
```

And two text files matching the `name` attribute values (with an added `.txt`):

```
.
├── step-a.txt  # contains the text: "Step A error logs ..."
└── step-b.txt  # contains the text: "Step B error logs ..."
```

The goal is to perform the replacement and end up with this JSON array:

```js
[ 
    { "name": "step-a", "message": "Step A error logs ..." },
    { "name": "step-b", "message": "Step B error logs ..." }
]
```

### Attempt

I tried something like this:

```sh
# the variable $INITIAL contains the initial JSON array
echo $INITIAL | jq -c '.[] | .message = "$(cat .displayName+".txt")"'
```

Is there a way to perform an operation like this with `jq` or is using extra bash logic necessary?
Thank you.

Comment: for those interested how the same query would look like using `jtc` (just showing an alternative solution): `<<<$INITIAL jtc -w'[name]:<N>P:[-1][message]' -eu cat {{N}}.txt \;` (PS. I'm the creator of the `jtc` unix tool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `input_filename` to achieve the goal very simply and efficiently.

For example, with the following in program.jq

```
# program.jq
(reduce inputs as $step ( {}; .[input_filename | rtrimstr(".txt")] = $step )) as $dict
| $a
| map(. + {message: $dict[.name] })
```

the following invocation would yield the expected result:

```
jq -n -f program.jq --argfile a array.json step-*.txt
```

### An alternative

Depending on your requirements, you might like to replace the last line of program.jq as given above by:

```
| map(.message = ($dict[.name] // .message))
```

### Alternatives to `--argfile`

If you prefer not to use `--argfile`, feel free to use `--argjson` or even `--slurpfile`, with appropriate adjustments to the above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried following your instructions like this: https://pastebin.com/puzqwxsd

Unfortunately, I received an error message.

Comment: The issue became related to the contents of the file, in particular the EOF flag if I'm not mistaken. Kindly review the error trace here: https://pastebin.com/MVZQEv40

Comment: In your second pastebin, the  "step" files contain raw strings, whereas in the Q as posted, they contain JSON strings.  If any of the "step" files contain raw strings, use the -R command-line option.  Note that if some of the "step" files contain raw strings and others contain JSON strings, you might want to make further adjustments to the jq program, depending on your exact requirements..

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables/arguments to `jq` using:

```
jq -r --arg first $1
```

- **$1** being your variable (which you can do: `_fileContents="$( cat step-a.txt )"` )
- **first** is the variable name you want to create (which you can use inside the `jq` command like a bash variable ( `$_fileContents` );

An example from one of my scripts:

```
export techUser=$(jq -r --arg first $1 '.Environment[].Servers[] | select (.Address | contains($first)) | ."Technical User"' $serverlist)
```

I hope this has helped you finding a way to make it work ;)